# File upload works only on some specific routes from Ionic app

Tags: node.js, angular, express, ionic-framework, file-upload

I've got a problem that is impossible to post the code here or reproduce. I am using Express with multer on the backend and Ionic 4.

When I try to upload a file on route `/a/b` everything works ok, when using the same code to upload another file to route `/c/d` I get a 413 error (with the exact same file). With Postman the uploads work on all routes.

I've tried to change the route name but still nothing works from the app. I've also tried different NODE_ENV and ionic env, even commenting out all the other routes and middleware on the server and still no luck.

Comment: Without looking at the code, can't help it! Maybe you will be missing something between the two routes...